# How can I change the format of the Infragistics UltraDateTimeEditor?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I need by default to set the format like "dd-MMM-yyyy" in UltraDateTimeEditor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have acces to infragistics controls, but a quick look [here](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.2/CLR2.0/) shows that there's a method `UltraDateTimeEditor.FormatString` that sounds like it might be useful. Have you tried setting that to `"dd-MMM-yyyy"`?